# How to use a DOT (.) in a product URL

Tags: magento-1.8, url

I wonder if it is possible to use a DOT (.) in a **product** URL in Magento. I want to create a **product** URL that looks something like this:

http://www.domain.com/galaxy-tab4-**10.1**.html

But when I try to do this then after saving the product the DOT in 10.1 is automatically changed in a DASH (-) and the URL becomes:

http://www.domain.com/galaxy-tab4-**10-1**.html

I have seen other websites that have DOTs in the path part of their URLs. I'm not sure why Magento doesn't accept them.

Any thoughts are welcome!

Comment: For anyone: To use DOTs in **category** URLs I used the same solution provided by @Marius below, and applied it to the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::formatUrlKey()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rewrite this method: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::formatUrlKey()`.
You need to change this line:

```
$urlKey = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', Mage::helper('catalog/product_url')->format($str));
```

What this basically means is, 'replace anything that's not alphanumeric with -'.
You need to make it allow dots also. Just add a dot in the regular expression.  `#[^0-9a-z\.]+#i`
<strike>(not sure if it should be escaped `\.` - test them both)</strike>.
Seams like it should be escaped.
Thanks @FabianBlechschmidt for the crash course in regex.

Comment: It should be escaped, because . is everything. If you want the dot \. is the right regex

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. Thanks for the correction. I changed the answer.

Comment: Using the `\.` works like a charm, thanks guys!!

Comment: There was an edit suggestion on the answer proposed by an anonymous user that I rejected because it seamed to change a lot of of the answer. It may be useful because I'm lousy at regex. This was it. "*(. does not need escaping inside a character class. It only has meaning outside of [])*"

Comment: The edit seems to be correct. Note tested with code but I did put the regex into http://www.regexr.com/ and it appears to match either way.

Comment: With the \. in the character class it will not replace either the '\' character or the '.' character, which is likely not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this fulfill your requirement, Magento has feature to manage url for products

Refer to [Creating Url Rewrites](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-url-rewrites)

Comment: I was looking for the answer provided by @Marius. But thanks anyway!!